# GParted wont resize extended partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

I have dual booted windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have decided that I need more space on my Ubuntu partition. I used `gparted` on a Live CD to shrink my Windows 7 partition (`/dev/sda3`) but when i try to resize the extended partition (`/dev/sda4`), which houses my linux partition (`/dev/sda6`), the right click options are greyed out and there is a key next to the extended partition.

I have resized the partitions within the extended partition before to provide room, but now I can go no further with that, and need to grow the extended partition. The free space lies to the left of the extended partition and there is a small amount of free space directly to the right as well.

Also, within the extended partition is `/dev/sda5` (`ntfs`) , which I have no idea what is on it, but most of the space (3.42GB) is used, `/dev/sda6` (`ext4`, mount point: `/`), my partition containing Linux, and `/dev/sda7` (`linux-swap`). I hope you guys can help me with this because I really don't want to screw something up while trying to resize the extended partition.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is likely that the extended partition is locked because your LiveCD environment is swapping to the swap partition which is inside of the extended partition.

Right-click on the swap partition and select "Swap off"

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked beautifully and now I have more space to use.