# Remove Edubuntu from Triple Boot

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, edubuntu

I have a computer that has Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04, and Edubuntu installed together. I would like to know how to remove Edubuntu from this configuration and then add the unallocated data to Windows 7 instead of it staying under sda 4. Edubuntu is sda 7.

[This is what GParted looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILUb3.png)

[GParted telling me that I can't extend sda3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdyNh.jpg)

Comment: rule of thumb: dont mess with windows partitions. You most likely want to back up all data and wipe the whole drive for a clean reinstall w/ a more recent Ubuntu (14.04 is LTS too)

Comment: @F.S. Would it just be easier to uninstall Ubuntu and then reinstall it? Also, I haven't upgraded cause 13.04 and 13.10 wouldn't run correctly on my computer. Made it run slowly and freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GParted to delete the partition with Edubuntu and resize another partition.

1. Delete sda7.
2. Unmount (sda5) or swap off (sda6) any logical partitions through the context menu.
3. Shrink sda4.
4. Grow sda3. (This step can be done last in Windows if you don't trust the Linux NTFS tools to do the job right.)
5. Commit the changes.
6. Finally, you have to open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me remove Edubuntu! That's part of my question fixed. Is there a way to change the unallocated data from the extended partition so I can increase the size of the windows partition? Or would it be easier to remove/reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes... just resize **/dev/sda3** by increasing it...

Comment: Whoops, it seemed to have worked for a minute. Okay, my problem is that the Unallocated data is under sda4 and it will not allow me to increase sda3's file size. I'll put the pictures in the question.

Comment: You probably need to shrink the extended partition container in slot 4 (sda4) before you can extend the 3rd partition (sda3).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for the suggestion but GParted isn't allowing me to shrink the extended partition. The most it will allow me to do is create a new Logical Partition from the unallocated space (Which is still part of the extended one), which doesn't help me with moving the extra space into my windows partition.

Comment: You're likely running into the problem “[GParted wont resize extended partitions](https://askubuntu.com/a/213835/175814)“ (answer included).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for showing me that but unfortunately all that has changed is that I can now shrink linux-swap.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to unmount all other logical partitions as well, namely sda5. You should be able to do that through the context menu of GParted.

Comment: Thank you @DavidFoerster! I've moved the unallocated space over and extended the partition. Thank you so much for your help!