# Expand partition to use free space

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage

[image][image: a]I have searched here on this site and others on the web and have tried to expand sda6 after removing several other OS/partitions with GParted...  no success.
Please guide me to the instructions or help!
I want to use the entire hard disk for this Ubuntu 15.04 installation currently on sda6.
Tried to post a screen snapshot of GParted but notified I need "10 reputation" to do so...  that is not helpful to solving problems for a newcomer to the site. 
 end rant.

I am booted via Ubuntu live USB.
I have deleted all previous partitions and am left with:

```
/dev/sda1 ext4 size 201 MiB used 140.05 MiB unused 60.95 MiB
unallocated size 174.53 GiB
/dev/sda2 extended size 123.37 GiB 
/dev/sda6 ext4 size 121.37 GiB used 115.02 unused 6.34 GiB flag = boot
/dev/sda5 linux-swap size 2.0 GiB
```

Why is sda6 mounted?
I did "swapoff" as suggested...
still can not resize partition.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to add the 174GiB of unallocated space to sda6?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do.  I want to use as much of the hard drive space as possible for the current Ubuntu installation.

Comment: when I tried to expand sda6 to unallocated space it looked like it was reducing te size of sda6 so I cancelled it...  already backed up all data

Comment: Can you increase the size of sda2?

Comment: Besides, now you can add the pic ;)

Comment: I figured out how to upload the screenshot...

Comment: screenshot uploaded

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: No sda2 "resize/move" is grayed out/not available

Comment: possible duplicate of [GParted wont resize extended partitions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/213830/gparted-wont-resize-extended-partitions) You're experiencing the same issue here.

Comment: further.. as you can see the key flag on sda2, has no option to unmount and OS is booted from USB live

Comment: As the dupe suggest, disable the swap partition.

Comment: disabled swap partition as suggested... no help.

Comment: clicked on information for sda6 (now sda5 is sda6 after swapoff) and it shows "mounted"  why? I am booted via live USB

Comment: The labels remain, nothing changed. And it shows as mounted because you (accidentally) mounted it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!  Thank you seppi!
My machine hardware or the live USB OS was slow to respond to the changes suggested/made.
Swapoff and wait.... then unmount sda4.
Thank you again seppi for your help and patience!